# Which statement is true regarding the centroid?

Tags: geometry

From a point $P$ on the circle $x^{2} + y^{2} = 4r^{2}$, tangents are drawn to $x^{2} + y^{2} = r^{2}$ at $Q$ and $R$. Then which of the following statement(s) are true regarding the centroid of $ΔPQR$

$A.$ is at a distance $r$ from chord $QR$.;

$B.$ lies on $x^{2} + y^{2} = r^{2}$

$C.$ is at a distance $1.5r$ from $P$

$D.$ doesn't lie on the line joining the origin and $P$

**My take:** $B$

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $O$ be the centre of the circles. By symmetry the centroid lies on the line $OP$.

Where on $OP$? Join $Q$ and $R$, and let $M$ be the point where $OP$ meets $QR$. Then by properties of the centroid, the centroid lies on $PM$, one-third of the way up from $M$ towards $P$.

Note that $PO=2r$ and $OQ=r$. So $\angle QPO$ is $30^\circ$. Computation (special angles or Pythagorean Theorem) shows that $PM=\frac{3}{2} r$.

The point $X$ where the little circle meets $OP$ **is**  therefore $1/3$ of the way up from $M$, since $XP=r$.  It follows that $X$ is the centroid.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Can you see Oklid's relation in  the picture? (Focus on $\triangle PQO$)

Comment: aye aye captain.